# Importing one long line of data into R

Tags: r

I have a large data file consisting of a single line of text. The format resembles

```
Cat    14  Dog    15  Horse  16
```

I'd eventually like to get it into a `data.frame` (so in the above example, I'd have two variables, `Animal` and `Number`). The number of characters in each "line" is fixed.

Any suggestions?

*Edit:* Thanks for all the suggestions. They solved the problem exactly as I asked. Unfortunately after running it I learned that I have missing data. However, the number of characters is still fixed. The example then becomes

```
Cat    14         15  Horse  16
```

with each line containing 11 characters (including spaces), animals being the first 7 and numbers being the next four.

This revision has been posted as a new question: [Importing one long line of data with spaces into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390943).

Comment: Congratulations: userNNNNNN: I think this might be a new record for the most rapid accumulation of workable answers in under 30 minutes.

Comment: Yep.  I guess, if anything, we answered the "Any suggestions?" part of your question!

Comment: You've moved the goalposts! Suggest you start a new question (and accept someone's answer as the answer by ticking it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This solution takes full advantage of `scan()`'s `what` argument, and seems simpler (to me) than any of the others:

```
x <- scan(file = textConnection("Cat 14 Dog 15 Horse 16"), 
          what = list(Animal=character(), Number=numeric()))

# Convert x (at this point a list) into a data.frame
as.data.frame(x)
#   Animal Number
# 1    Cat     14
# 2    Dog     15
# 3  Horse     16
```

Comment: +1 Well done.  I've seen this paradigm before, but it didn't come to mind.

Comment: @Andrie -- Thanks.  Yeah, scan is pretty amazing.  I just now took a peek under the hood of `read.table` (since `scan` is the engine for that).  It's worth a glance. The third call to `scan` uses this same construction to read in the data (once each column's class has been determined).

Comment: Minor nit:  all dataframes are of `class` list, but are `typeof` dataframe, while items which are `typeof` list are also `class` list. `as.data.frame` leaves the class of x as list while changing its typeof to dataframe.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- I agree there's some sublety here, but I think you've got that backwards. `class(as.data.frame(list(1:4, 5:8)))` returns a class of `data.frame` for me (which is why so many generic methods are able to dispatch a `data.frame`-specific method). `typeof(as.data.frame(list(1:4, 5:8)))` returns a typeof `list`, which is also as it should be.

Comment: Yep, Josh, sorry for being braincramped and swapping the class and typeof values.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution using a variety of tools/hacks, specifically:

- `strplit` to split on space characters (`\\s`)
- `unlist` to coerce the list returned by `strsplit` into a vector
- `matrix` to turn the vector into the appropriate shape
- `data.frame` to allow for columns of different mode
- `as.character` and `as.numeric` to convert the Count column from a factor

Here's everything put together:

```
txt <- "Cat 14 Dog 15 Horse 16"

out <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(txt, "\\s")), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Animal", "Count"))))
out$Count <- as.numeric(as.character(out$Count))
str(out)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Animal: Factor w/ 3 levels "Cat","Dog","Horse": 1 2 3
 $ Count : num  14 15 16
```

Answer (score 3):

Method 1: (extracting from long vector with seq()

```
> inp <- scan(textConnection("Cat 14 Dog 15 Horse 16"), what="character")
Read 6 items
> data.frame(animal = inp[seq(1,length(inp), by=2)], 
             numbers =as.numeric(inp[seq(2,length(inp), by=2)]))
  animal numbers
1    Cat      14
2    Dog      15
3  Horse      16
```

Method 2: (using the "what" argument to scan to greater effect)

```
> inp <- data.frame(scan(textConnection("Cat 14 Dog 15 Horse 16"), 
                     what=list("character", "numeric")))
Read 3 records
> names(inp) <- c("animals", "numbers")
> inp
  animals numbers
1     Cat      14
2     Dog      15
3   Horse      16
```

This is a refinement of the Method 2: (was worried about possibility of very long column names in the result from scan() so I read the help page again and added names to the what argument values:

```
inp <- data.frame(scan(textConnection("Cat 14 Dog 15 Horse 16"), 
                        what=list( animals="character", 
                                   numbers="numeric")))
Read 3 records
> inp
  animals numbers
1     Cat      14
2     Dog      15
3   Horse      16
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
# read the line
r <- read.csv("exa.Rda",sep=" ", head=F)
# every odd number index is an animal
animals <- r[,(1:ncol(r)-1)%%2==0]
# every even number index is a number
numbers <- r[,(1:ncol(r))%%2==0]
# flipping the animal row into a column
animals <- t(animals)
# flipping the number row into a column
numbers <- t(numbers)
# putting the data together
mydata <- data.frame(animals, numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach

```
string <- readLines(textConnection(x))
string <- gsub("(\\d+)", "\\1\n", string, perl = TRUE)
dat    <- read.table(text = string, sep = "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the white space is a delimiter, you can use the following mechanism:

- Use `scan` to read the file
- Convert the results to a `matrix`, then to a `data.frame`

The code:

```
x <- scan(file=textConnection("
Cat 14 Dog 15 Horse 16
"), what="character")

xx <- as.data.frame(matrix(x, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
names(xx) <- c("Animal", "Number")
xx$Number <- as.numeric(xx$Number)
```

The results:

```
xx

  Animal Number
1    Cat      1
2    Dog      2
3  Horse      3
```

Comment: I think you want an `as.character()` in there before the `as.numeric()` right?

Comment: ooo, didn't realize `scan()` would return a character vector like that, interesting!