# Importing one long line of data with spaces into R

Tags: r

This question is a followup to my previous question, [Importing one long line of data into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389913).

I have a large data file consisting of a single line of text. The format resembles

```
Cat    14         15  Horse  16
```

I'd eventually like to get it into a data.frame. In the above example I would end up with two variables, two variables, Animal and Number. The number of characters in each "line" is fixed, so in the example above each line contains 11 characters, animals being the first 7 and numbers being the next four.

So what I'd like is a data frame that looks like:

```
Animal Number
   Cat     14
    NA     15
 Horse     16
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Are you saying this is a fixed width file? Each animal has 7 characters and each number has 4 characters?

Comment: Why did you repeat this question?  I just saw that.  i'm not getting the difference?

Comment: +1 for editing the question so that it is clear what you are asking about. Thanks for that prompt revision.

Comment: @Tyler - One of the animals in this example has escaped the playpen so can't be found anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file with `read.fwf`, specifying the column widths and the number of columns:

```
inp.fwf <- read.fwf("tmp.txt", widths = rep(c(7, 4), times = 3), as.is = TRUE)
```

Here the argument `times = 3` works for your sample data; for your real file, you'll have to indicate how many pairs there are and change `times` accordingly. If you don't know how many entries you have, this might work:

```
inp.rl <- readLines("tmp.txt")
nchar(inp.rl)/11
```

This will give you a data.frame with one row and many columns. You need to break that into many rows and two columns:

```
inp.mat <- matrix(inp.fwf, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
```

This will get you the correct shape for your data. The animal names are stored as character vectors, which you'll probably want to change into factors, but at this point all the data is in R, so you can easily tweak it.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with vectorized substring function.

```
x <- readLines(textConnection("Cat    14         15  Horse  16  "))
idx <- seq.int(1,nchar(x),by=11)
vsubstr <- Vectorize(substr,vectorize.args=c("start","stop"))
dat <- data.frame(Animal= vsubstr(x,idx,idx+6),
                  Number= as.numeric(vsubstr(x,idx+7,idx+10)))
```

Comment: +1 Nicely done.  I thought about using substr but the code I tried felt ugly; your use of Vectorize makes it looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the 15 is all about from the way you described data it should be animal-space-count-space-animal...

Anyway if the 15 should not be there here is one approach.

```
list1<-"Cat 14 Horse 16" 

x <- unlist(strsplit(list1, " "))
            x <- as.data.frame(matrix(x, length(x)/2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
            x[, 2] <- as.numeric(as.character(x[, 2]))
            x[, 1] <- as.character(x[, 1])
names(x) <-c('animal', 'count')   
x
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a text file, `test.dat`, with repeated Animal Number pairs.

```
x <- scan("test.dat", what=list("", 0))
my.df <- data.frame(Animal = x[[1]], Number = x[[2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Tyler's use of `read.fwf` is perhaps cleaner, but here's another possible method.

```
x <- readLines(textConnection("Cat    14         15  Horse  16  "))
x <- matrix(strsplit(x, "")[[1]], nrow=11)
d <- data.frame(Animal = apply(x[1:7,], 2, paste, collapse=""),
                Number = as.numeric(apply(x[8:11,], 2, paste, collapse="")))
```